# Is it 100 million documents too much?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

Well, I am new to `mongo` and today morning I had a (bad) idea. I was playing around with indexes from the shell and decided to create a large collection with many documents (100 million). So I executed the following command:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) { 
    for (j = 100; j > 0; j--) { 
        for (k = 1; k <= 100; k++) { 
            for (l = 100; l > 0; l--) {
                db.testIndexes.insert({a:i, b:j, c:k, d:l})
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the things didn't go as I expected:

1. It took 45 minutes complete the request.
2. It created 16 GB data on my hard disk.
3. It used 80% of my RAM (8GB total) and it won't release them till I restarted my PC.

As you can see in the photo below, as the number of documents inside the collection was growing, the time of the insertion of documents was growing as well. I suggest that by the last modification time of the data files:

[image]

Is this an expected behavior? I don't think that 100 million **simple** documents are too much.

P.S. I am now really afraid to run an `ensureIndex` command.

**Edit:**

I executed the following command:

```
> db.testIndexes.stats()
{
        "ns" : "test.testIndexes",
        "count" : 100000000,
        "size" : 7200000056,
        "avgObjSize" : 72.00000056,
        "storageSize" : 10830266336,
        "numExtents" : 28,
        "nindexes" : 1,
        "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
        "paddingFactor" : 1,
        "systemFlags" : 1,
        "userFlags" : 0,
        "totalIndexSize" : 3248014112,
        "indexSizes" : {
                "_id_" : 3248014112
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

So, the default index on `_id` has more than 3GB size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It took 45 minutes complete the request.

Not surprised.

> It created 16 GB data on my hard disk.

As @Abhishek states everything seems fine, MongoDB does use a fair amount of space without compression currently (that's coming later hopefully).

It seems that the data size is about 7.2GB while the average object size is 72 bytes, it seems this is working perfectly (since 72 bytes fits into 7.2GB) with the 3GB overhead of the _id index it seems that the storage size of 10GB is fitting quite well.

Though I am concerned that it has used 6GB more than the statistics say it needs to, that might need more looking into. I am guessing it is because of how MongoDB wrote to the data files, it might even be because you was not using a non fire and forget write concern (`w>0`), all in all; hmmm.

> It used 80% of my RAM (8GB total) and it won't release them till I restarted my PC.

MongoDB will try and take as much RAM as the OS will let it. If the OS lets it take 80% then 80% it will take. This is actually a good sign, it shows that MongoDB has the right configuration values to store your working set efficiently.

When running `ensureIndex` `mongod` will never free up RAM. It simply has no hooks for that, instead the OS will shrink its allocated block to make room for more (or should rather).

Answer (score 2):

This is an expected behavior, mongo db files starts with filesize 16MB ( test.0 ), and grow till 2GB and then 2GB is constant.

100 million ( 16 GB ) documents in nothing.
You can run ensureIndex, it shouldn't take much time.

You need not to restart your pc, the moment other process needed RAM, mongod will free RAM.

FYI : test.12 is completely empty.

I am guessing you are not worried about 16GB size just for 100 million documents ?